# teamcity - deploy artifacts to nexus without mvn deploy

Tags: java, build, teamcity, nexus, teamcity-8.0

I can't find anywhere if TeamCity is able to deploy build artifacts to nexus, when job has finished (like Jenkins does), and not by running "mvn deploy". Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe as a build feature.

Comment: Why do you not want to run mvn deploy? Thats what Jenkins basically does as well.

Comment: @ManfredMoser Because the difference is that Jenkins runs the deploy after the entire build is finished and if you run just mvn deploy it will do that for every module.

Comment: You could do one Maven build step that runs mvn clean install and then as a separate step mvn deploy. That way if they first one fails, nothing will be deployed.